# How to interpret insignificant intercept in logistic regression with orthogonal polynomial encoding

Tags: logistic, interpretation, model, ordinal-data, intercept

I have conducted a logistic regression.

```r
Model <- logistf(A ~ C, family ="binomial"(link = "logit"), data=Data)
```

The dependent variable is binary (1,0) The sole independent variable is ordinal with 3 levels. I've included the relevant parts of the summary below.

```r
                   coef       se(coef)    Chisq           p
(Intercept)       -0.05       0.36        0.023       0.87
C.L               1.6         0.74        6.67        0.009
C.Q              -0.2         0.51        0.31        0.57
```

Please note here L and Q refer to linear and quadratic effects. This is a polynomial contrast. The independent variable is ordinal with 3 levels low<medium<high.

How can I interpret this summary? As I understand it the log odds of a "success" linearly increase by 1.6 with the independent variable "C". However what are the log odds of a success when my independent is at its lowest level, if the intercept is insignificant?

**EDIT to include info from comment**

```r
> contr.poly(3)
                .L         .Q
[1,] -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
[2,] -7.850462e-17 -0.8164966
[3,]  7.071068e-01  0.4082483
```

**EDIT 2 More info from comments**

```r
> head(Data)
                    C           A
1                Medium         0
2                Medium         0
3                  High         1
4                  High         1
5                Medium         1
6                Medium         0

#note C is 3 levels - Low, medium, high. Low simply isn't shown at the top of the dataframe.

Data$C <- factor(Data$C, levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"), ordered = TRUE)
Data$A <- Data$A <- as.integer(Data$A)

Model <- logistf(A ~ C, family ="binomial"(link = "logit"), data=Data)

summary(Model)
                         coef  se(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95      Chisq           p
(Intercept)       -0.05228334 0.3693310 -0.8607010  0.5764470 0.02318317 0.878981724
C.L                1.60842992 0.7458429  0.3711041  3.2751171 6.67898157 0.009755635
C.Q               -0.26863239 0.5120064 -1.3463216  0.6337436 0.31863128 0.572431359

Likelihood ratio test=7.75 on 2 df, p=0.020, n=82
Wald test = 6.036922 on 2 df, p = 0.048

Covariance-Matrix:
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.1364054 -0.2044094  0.1200786
[2,] -0.2044094  0.5562817 -0.2503493
[3,]  0.1200786 -0.2503493  0.2621505
```

**EDIT 3 More info from comments**

```r
> Model$predict[1:5]
[1] 0.5416667 0.5416667 0.7261905 0.7261905 0.5416667
```

Comment: Apologies. Just realised that I misinterpreted what I read before, so I have removed that sentence. I was reading this https://support.sas.com/kb/23/136.html

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260209/the-difference-between-with-or-without-intercept-model-in-logistic-regression/260214#260214

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm afraid my actual understanding of the maths here is pretty poor. Would you be able to describe what I can actually conclude from my data here?

Comment: Three additional suggestions. I would add "with orthogonal polynomial encoding" to your question title. Second, I would add how the C.L and C.Q variables are actually coded, rather than the coding of your C variable (maybe as simple as the output of `contr.poly(3)`, but hard to know for sure). Third, I would entertain the possibility that with this type of encoding, the intercept is not particularly meaningful and that worrying about it a waste of your time.

Comment: Thank you @DimitriyV.Masterov I have tried to add the information you suggested. Please let me know if I've misunderstood. I'm very unfamiliar with this type of encoding, I'm working with R and this is what was returned. You may be right that I don't need to worry about the intercept (I have no idea), so I guess my issue is just interpreting what this output is telling me as a whole.

Comment: It is telling you that the data is consistent with a linear effects. Going from low to medium has the same effect on the log-odds as going from medium to high, which are half of the effect you get from going from low to high. Cubic effects are not well supported. How the intercept fits into all that, I don't really know.

Comment: Is the link correct? Shouldn't it be logit? If it's really probit, then all the log-odds stuff goes out the window.

Comment: So am I right in saying the log odds increase by 1.6 by moving from low to medium (or medium to high)? Does it tell me the baseline log odds?

Comment: Apologies, yes it is logit - i've altered it now. The rest should be correct.

Comment: First, this is a Firth logit, not a logit/logistic or a probit. Second, there is no mention of any encoding, so either your independent categorical variable is hot encoded, the orthogonal encoding is already done on the data, or the OP encoding is done automatically (which is least likely).

Comment: This can be resolved if you show us what the first few rows of Data look like, show us the actual code that you typed, with the output that you want help in interpreting that results from the code you actually typed. We have wasted a fair bit of time here already trying to fill the gaps between what you say you are doing, what you think you are doing, and what you actually are doing.

Comment: I have added the information you have suggested. I apologize for taking up your time. I am extremely grateful for the effort you are putting in here. I recognise I'm probably not supplying the information needed, this is unfortunately because I'm a little out of my depth with this level of statistics.

Comment: Interpreting the "significance" of an intercept can be tricky. Although not an issue here, when there are interaction terms the intercept (under standard treatment coding of categorical variables) simply represents the estimated outcome when all categorical variables are at reference conditions and continuous predictors are at value of 0. Simply re-coding categorical predictors or centering continuous predictors thus can change the apparent "significance" of an intercept, which is just a test of whether the estimated value of the intercept equals 0 _under that coding of the predictors_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined C as an ordered variable, which it is, so `logistf` automatically converts C to an orthogonal polynomial representation, which makes things harder to interpret. Why does R do this?

Orthogonal polynomial encoding is a form of trend analysis in that it is looking for the linear, quadratic and cubic trends in the effect of a categorical variable. Here you only have three values of C, so we can only do linear and cubic. This type of coding system should be used only with an ordinal variable in which the levels are equally spaced (which may or may not be the case in your data, the coding is evenly spaced, but the underlying variables may not be). In R it is not necessary to compute these values since this contrast can be obtained for any categorical variable by using the `contr.poly` function that I asked you to use. This the default contrast used for ordered factor variables. This makes it easier to find a functional form that will allow you to model your categorical variables as if they were more continuous. This can help impose more structure on the effects, compared to something more flexible, where every category can have its own effect.

The fact that C.L coefficient is positive and significant, tells you that the data is consistent with a linear trend of C on the log odds: each time C goes up by 1, log odds go up by the same amount. The fact that quadratic is negative, means you have a deceleration in that trend (slower growth), but it is not significant.

Here is a reproducible example with some comments interspersed (reproducible code will be below):

```r
    > library(logistf)
    > library(boot)
    > 
    > # Calculate your OP model predictions for C=1,2,3
    > inv.logit(-0.05228334 + 1.60842992*( -7.071068e-01) + 
               (-0.26863239)*0.4082483)
    [1] 0.2142856
    > inv.logit(-0.05228334 + 1.60842992*(-7.850462e-17) + 
                (-0.26863239)*-0.8164966)
    [1] 0.5416667
    > inv.logit(-0.05228334 + 1.60842992*(7.071068e-01) + 
               (-0.26863239)*0.4082483)
    [1] 0.7261905
```

As you can see, this matches 2 of the 3 predictions that you reported. Now for the toy example:

```r
    > # Toy Example
    > raw <- 'A C   cL  cQ
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 0 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 1 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 1 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + 1 2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 3   .7071068    .4082483
    + 1 1   -.7071068   .4082483
    + '
    
    > Data <- read.table(text = raw, header = TRUE)
    > Data$C <- factor(Data$C, levels = c(1, 2, 3), ordered = TRUE)
    > 
    > # Show the orthogonal polynomial representation of C
    > unique(Data[,c("C","cL","cQ")])
      C            cL         cQ
    1 2 -7.850000e-17 -0.8164966
    2 1 -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
    7 3  7.071068e-01  0.4082483
    > contr.poly(3)
                    .L         .Q
    [1,] -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
    [2,] -7.850462e-17 -0.8164966
    [3,]  7.071068e-01  0.4082483
```

As you can see, the values returned by `contr.poly(3)` match what is in my data. We will fit the model, but not a Firth logit, just a normal logit (but that should not really matter; also not clear to me what you are doing at home):

```r
    > # Plain Logit Model with Orthogonal Polynomial
    > op_model<-logistf(A~C, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=Data, 
                       firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)
    > summary(op_model)
    logistf(formula = A ~ C, data = Data, pl = TRUE, firth = FALSE, 
        family = binomial(link = "logit"))
    
    Model fitted by Standard ML
    Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood 
    
                      coef  se(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95     Chisq            p
    (Intercept) -0.9098647 0.2733188 -1.4739880 -0.3932878 12.372954 0.0004355978
    C.L          1.1091790 0.4580922  0.2432744  2.0621977  6.387326 0.0114938060
    C.Q          0.5206835 0.4882321 -0.4030296  1.5437748  1.191198 0.2750880661
    
    Likelihood ratio test=7.786674 on 2 df, p=0.02037724, n=74
    Wald test = 7.538426 on 2 df, p = 0.02307021
    
    Covariance-Matrix:
                [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
    [1,]  0.07470317 -0.01678486 -0.01164408
    [2,] -0.01678486  0.20984848 -0.02055717
    [3,] -0.01164408 -0.02055717  0.23837055
```

You can even see what R is actually doing to C with this bit of code:

```r
    > head(model.matrix(logistf(Data$A~Data$C, family=binomial(link="logit"), firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)))
      (Intercept)      Data$C.L   Data$C.Q
    1           1 -7.850462e-17 -0.8164966
    2           1 -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
    3           1 -7.850462e-17 -0.8164966
    4           1 -7.850462e-17 -0.8164966
    5           1 -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
    6           1 -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
```

Now we will do the same thing using the cL and cQ variables I entered myself. We should see the same model summary as above:

```r
    > # Plain Logit Model with Orthogonal Polynomial by Hand
    > op_model_by_hand<-logistf(A~cL+cQ, family=binomial(link="logit"), 
                               data=Data, firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)
    > summary(op_model_by_hand)
    logistf(formula = A ~ cL + cQ, data = Data, pl = TRUE, firth = FALSE, 
        family = binomial(link = "logit"))
    
    Model fitted by Standard ML
    Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood 
    
                      coef  se(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95     Chisq            p
    (Intercept) -0.9098647 0.2733188 -1.4739880 -0.3932878 12.372954 0.0004355978
    cL           1.1091789 0.4580922  0.2432744  2.0621977  6.387326 0.0114938060
    cQ           0.5206835 0.4882321 -0.4030296  1.5437748  1.191198 0.2750880661
    
    Likelihood ratio test=7.786674 on 2 df, p=0.02037724, n=74
    Wald test = 7.538426 on 2 df, p = 0.02307021
    
    Covariance-Matrix:
                [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
    [1,]  0.07470317 -0.01678486 -0.01164408
    [2,] -0.01678486  0.20984847 -0.02055717
    [3,] -0.01164408 -0.02055717  0.23837054
```

This way to represent C is somewhat unintuitive. The specific values of cL and cQ themselves have no meaning to us because they were computed by R to make all the contrasts linearly independent of one another. This kind of encoding is just one of [at least 9 possible ways to encode categorical variables](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/). For OP, it probably does not make too much sense to think hard about the intercept insignificance. And it certainly does not mean that you should take it out. You should never decide which variables to omit from the model based on statistical significance only.

This is how you might do the one-hot encoding that lends itself to easier interpretation:

```r
    > # Remove the constraint that C is ordered to get one-hot encoded version
    > Data$C <- factor(Data$C, levels = c(1, 2,3), ordered = FALSE)
    > oh_model<-logistf(A~C, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=Data, 
                       firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)
    > summary(oh_model)
    logistf(formula = A ~ C, data = Data, pl = TRUE, firth = FALSE, 
        family = binomial(link = "logit"))
    
    Model fitted by Standard ML
    Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood Profile Likelihood 
    
                      coef  se(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95       Chisq            p
    (Intercept) -1.4816045 0.4954337 -2.5755111 -0.5899917 11.55500406 0.0006756716
    C2           0.1466035 0.7057522 -1.2656065  1.5604230  0.04313599 0.8354694171
    C3           1.5686159 0.6478402  0.3440419  2.9163880  6.38732576 0.0114938060
    
    Likelihood ratio test=7.786674 on 2 df, p=0.02037724, n=74
    Wald test = 7.538426 on 2 df, p = 0.02307021
    
    Covariance-Matrix:
               [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
    [1,]  0.2454545 -0.2454545 -0.2454545
    [2,] -0.2454545  0.4980861  0.2454545
    [3,] -0.2454545  0.2454545  0.4196970
```

Personally, this is the model I would use myself with your data. You can use it to calculate the baseline odds from the intercept, and the exponentiated coefficients will give you the multiplicative effect on those baseline odds.

I don't think there is any way to interpret the OP model in the same way. I also don't think it makes sense to treat C as an ordered variable here and try to find trends when it only has three values.

---

**Code:**

```r
    library(logistf)
    library(boot)
    
    # Calculate your OP model predictions for C=1,2,3
    inv.logit(-0.05228334 + 1.60842992*( -7.071068e-01) + (-0.26863239)*0.4082483)
    inv.logit(-0.05228334 + 1.60842992*(-7.850462e-17) + (-0.26863239)*-0.8164966)
    inv.logit(-0.05228334 + 1.60842992*(7.071068e-01) + (-0.26863239)*0.4082483)
    
    # Toy Example
    raw <- 'A   C   cL  cQ
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    0   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    1   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    1   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    1   2   -7.85e-17   -.8164966
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   3   .7071068    .4082483
    1   1   -.7071068   .4082483
    '
    
    Data <- read.table(text = raw, header = TRUE)
    Data$C <- factor(Data$C, levels = c(1, 2, 3), ordered = TRUE)
    
    # Show the orthogonal polynomial representation of C
    unique(Data[,c("C","cL","cQ")])
    contr.poly(3)
    
    # Plain Logit Model with Orthogonal Polynomial
    op_model<-logistf(A~C, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=Data, firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)
    summary(op_model)
    head(model.matrix(logistf(Data$A~Data$C, family=binomial(link="logit"), firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)))
    
    # Plain Logit Model with Orthogonal Polynomial by Hand
    op_model_by_hand<-logistf(A~cL+cQ, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=Data, firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)
    summary(op_model_by_hand)
    
    # Remove the constraint that C is ordered to get one-hot encoded version
    Data$C <- factor(Data$C, levels = c(1, 2,3), ordered = FALSE)
    oh_model<-logistf(A~C, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=Data, firth=FALSE, pl=TRUE)
    summary(oh_model)
```

Answer (score 2):

The predictor is categorical (in fact ordinal) with three levels. Since you are representing it with a linear and quadratic term (I suppose), it matters which numerical values you have used to represent it. Three parameters gives a saturated model, and the intercept is an intrinsic part of that description, so it does not really make much sense to look at tests of the coefficients individually. If you used a dummy variable representation, you would get also three parameters, with identical fitted values (but different coefficients.)

The most practical way to represent your results would be by plotting the estimated probabilities as a function of the ordinal variable, say with numerical values 1,2,3 (if those are what you used.) Since you didn't tell us I cannot plot it for you.

If you want to look at individual hypothesis tests, start with the highest polynomial order, your `C.Q`. That seems to be insignificant, so you can consider a reduced linear model. Since `C.L` have a low p-value, you should stop the reduction there. You should never consider to remove the intercept!

Comment: The numerical values used are 1, 2, 3. Model$predict[1:3] yields 0.5416667 0.5416667 0.7261905. Is this what you need? Sorry if it's not, I'm a little out of my depth.

Comment: Can you please add that information to the Q as an edit, togetger with relevant code, so we can be sure what you are doing?

Comment: I have added the section on Model$predict. I think I have added everything included in this model in the code now.

Comment: That is good, but what you jave wrote in the Q is different from what in the comment .... ? can you correct, and explain? Maybe share (a link to) the data, so we can show some examples in answers, that way it should be clearer.