# Interaction term's significance changes by including the intercept. How to decide if intercept is to be kept or not?

Tags: interaction, intercept

I am working on a model (non-linear) of the form:

[image]

[image]

Should I have the intercept in the equation, as having one gives a different outcome (level of significance) to my interaction term 1, compared to not having the intercept?

Answer (score 2):

You should **almost never** leave the intercept out of the model, unless you have a very good reason, and what you have given is not a good reason. That p-value for an interaction changes is not a good reason.

Have a look at

- [When is it ok to remove the intercept in a linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model)
- [The difference between with or without intercept model in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260209/the-difference-between-with-or-without-intercept-model-in-logistic-regression)